# MPAndroidChart: multiple LineDataSet from LiveData in a LineChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, android-livedata

Looking at other examples, I see that the chart needs all the data sets at once and you cannot add them iteratively once they are ready. Am I wrong?

```
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
...
dataSets.add(d1);
dataSets.add(d2);
...
LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
mChart.setData(data);
```

My problem is that I hold the necessary data for the multiple LineDataSet in a database and access them through LiveData. To draw a single LineDataSet would be simple because I would write the logic of this inside stuff.observe{}.

```
stuff.observe(this, goodStuff -> {
    Data data = generateData(goodStuff);
    mChart.setData(data);
});
```

But now I have to observe multiple stuff and then set the data of multiple stuff to the chart.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add data *Dynamically/Real time*, just keep in mind that you also need to **notify** your chart about data in your observer,

```
stuff.observe(this, goodStuff -> {
    Data data = generateData(goodStuff);
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let the chart know it's data changed
    mChart.invalidate(); // refresh chart
});
```

Check more info from [**here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data#keep-in-mind)

Comment: I have multiple stuff to observe and the results of each stuff should go into an array of ILineDataSet before setting the data. But I guess it's fine. I'll create a LineData member in my class and add to it in each .observe, then notify and invalidate.